# Sort an array of strings by a part of the string or index?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, sorting, mergesort

I have written this program where I have it sorting my array of strings alphabetically. I want to be able to sort it by a different part of the string, numerically. (I am also using eclipse).
Here is what I have:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Merge;

public class sortNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method

    String[] age = {"Meredith Chicago #82", 
            "Brian Phoenix #45", "Jess Miami #26", 
            "Gunther NYC #53", "Frank Boise #4"};

    System.out.println("-----------------------------");

    //loop through array and print out unsorted string

    for(String i : age){
        System.out.printf("%25s\n", i); //to right-align

    }

    System.out.println("-----------------------------");

    Merge.sort(age);

    //loop through array and print sorted string

    for(String j: age){
        System.out.println(j); //this is where I am unsure of the right way
    }



    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
  }

}
```

For an output, I get this:

```
-----------------------------
     Meredith Chicago #82
        Brian Phoenix #45
           Jess Miami #26
          Gunther NYC #53
           Frank Boise #4
-----------------------------
Brian Phoenix #45
Frank Boise #4
Gunther NYC #53
Jess Miami #26
Meredith Chicago #82
-----------------------------
```

And obviously this is due to it looking at the beginning of the string. That's not an issue and of course, expected.

Can I set it to where it would look at the numbers? Can it be done by counting the indexes? Like for example, count up to but not including the `#` from the end (`-1`) index and sort by that? Ascending order of course. I'm still looking to use a for loop.

I was going to have at it without a loop, by creating separate objects for each piece of information, but then realized this would take forever and there would be too much code.

Comment: What is `Merge`? Where is it defined? If you are using the Java library sorting methods you can provide a custom `Comparator` implementation to sort any way you like, but we don't know if that's possible with the class you're using.

Comment: Yes, you can sort your array by the numerical part of the strings. Just split strings correctly, extract the number, convert it to int and do the sorting. Probably there are other ways to do it. Does it answer your question?  Or you want to someone to show you how to do that by providing a piece of code?

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm using the algs4.jar from http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/ which includes `Merge`. Also, here is the definition of `merge` http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/Merge.java.html.
From reading around, I THINK it may be possible. I am just unsure of how to implement it as I am a Java newbie.

Comment: @Nurzhan It does, I am sure it can be done because I believe it's a fairly simple concept, however, if you could provide some code explaining that, that would be helpful. I would like some guidance on the implementation and application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advice you to create separate objects for this type of data like this:

```
public class User implements Comparable<User> {
  private int mId;
  private String mName;

  public User(final int id, final String name) {
    mId = id;
    mString = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return mName;
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(final User lhs, final User rhs) {
    return Integer.compare(lhs.mId, rhs.mId);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s #%d", mName, mId);
  }
}
```

Here i've implemented `Comparable<User>` where you can override comparing type as you want. Here i simply comparing users on id.
After this, you can use `Collections.sort(List<User>)` or `Merge.sort(Comparable[])`, as you want and they will be sorted. Also, overriden `toString()` method gives an ability to output user info simply as `user.toString()`.

Comment: `((Integer) lhs.mId).compareTo(rhs.mId)` should be [`Integer.compare(lhs.mId, rhs.mId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-). Don't auto-box the integers just to compare them.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for advice! I will edit answer now. I've shown such way because i'm Android programmer, we have no native `Integer.compare(int, int)` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort an array using `Arrays.sort` and give it a custom comparator. For example, using Java 8:

```
Arrays.sort(age, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a.split("#")[1])));
```

While this code works, I would suggest creating a class to encapsulate the logic.

```
public class Person {
    public static Person decode(String line) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\w+) #(\\d+)").matcher(line);
        if (!matcher.matches())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal format");
        return new Person(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    }

    public int getAge() {...}
    public String getName() {...}
}
```

Then using streams your code can become much more explicit:

```
Arrays.stream(age)
    .map(Person::decode)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge))
    .forEach(...);
```